# How to move products, categories and attributes from one store to another - Magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento-1.8, category, attributes, products

I have a broken Magento store version 1.8.1 and I want to move to a fresh installed Magento 1.8.1 only products, categories and attributes. After this I will install any necessary extension.

Is there any free extension that can do this or can you give me the list of all tables that I must export from the old store?

EDIT: i have 11.000+ products and 200+ categories.
I have some extensions that are custom made for 1.8.1 and i do not know if they work fine on 1.9

Thanks,
Have a nice day

Comment: You DO NOT Want to do it that way, you should simply take your original database and getting it running with a fresh version of 1.8.1 - Why not use 1.9.1?

Answer (score 1):

Use Magento's import/export feature... I found nice article here

http://lero9.co.nz/magento-tips/how-to-export-your-magento-product-database-using-using-magentos-importexport-dataflow-profiles/